# Ubuntu 16.04 built-in back-up app (Deja-Dup) won't work

Tags: ubuntu-16.04

Just installed Ubuntu 16.04 and tried to activate the automatic back-up option with the built-in back-up software. When trying to run a back up, it says: `Failed to execute child process "duplicity" (No such file or directory)`. What's going on?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Run:

```
sudo apt-get install duplicity
```

This should fix that.

Comment: I also had to install python-gi (`sudo apt install python-gi`).

Answer (score 3):

If `sudo apt-get install duplicity` doesn't work, run:

```
apt-cache policy deja-dup-backend-gvfs
```

If it says `Installed: (none)`, run:

```
sudo apt-get install deja-dup-backend-gvfs
```

This worked for me in `Ubuntu 16.10`.